# Is there an event for when features are selected in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/select-features.html

Given the above examples, what extension points are there for hooking into when features are selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a precompose event to your layer when a singleclick event is triggered on your map. From here you can dispatch a change event on your select interaction.

```
yourmap.on('singleclick',function(event)){
    layer.once('precompose',function(event){
        yourSelectInteraction.dispatchChangeEvent();
    }
}

yourSelectInteraction.on('change',function(){
    //Do stuff with your selected features here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. Do you know why the change event is not dispatched automatically every time a feature is (un)selected ??

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that might be more intuitive than Danny's, and also seems to be the "official" way, see [this issue on ol3's GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1234).

Simply add the listener to the collection of selected features :

```
    mySelectInteraction.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e) {
        if (e.target.getArray().length === 0) {
            alert("no selected feature");
        } else {
            var feature = e.target.item(0);
            alert(feature.getId()); //or do something better with the feature !
        }
    });
```

Comment: As mentioned in the GitHub issue, you can also subscribe to the 'add' and 'remove' events on the features collection.

Comment: You can use `e.target.getLength()` instead of `e.target.getArray().length`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `featureselected` event handler:

This example is on a Vector layer:

```
featuresLayer.events.on({
    'featureselected': function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: is that openlayers 3? events is not defined.